# DryIoc - ASP.Net Core - Scope context per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dryioc

I want to use DryIoc in my application (ASP.Net Core 2.2).
I want to use the same instance of services during execution of the call of one API service. (During Http call / scoped context).
If it was in ASP.Net WebApi, I would like to have a scope per http context. In the DryIoc documentation, it is possible to use AsyncExecutionFlowScopeContext for WebApi.

But, with ASP.Net Core, I don't really understand how to use and declare a scope per request.

My code is based on this sample: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/tree/master/samples/DryIoc.AspNetCore.Sample

If I tried to resolve a service declared as ScopeService (Reuse.Scoped) I have the issue : Unable to resolve IScopedService IsResolutionCall
from Container without Scope.

For your information, the declaration of my container is like in the sample:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()

    // Enables controllers to be resolved by DryIoc, OTHERWISE resolved by infrastructure
    .AddControllersAsServices();

    var container = new Container(rules => rules.With(
        propertiesAndFields: request => 
        request.ServiceType.Name.EndsWith("Controller")
        ? PropertiesAndFields.Properties()(request)
        : null)
        .WithCaptureContainerDisposeStackTrace());

    Container = container;

    return container.WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(services,
        throwIfUnresolved: type => type.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
        // Your registrations are defined in CompositionRoot class
        .ConfigureServiceProvider<CompositionRoot>();
}
```

For the registration:

```
public CompositionRoot(IRegistrator r)
{
    r.Register<ISingletonService, SingletonService>(Reuse.Singleton);
    r.Register<ITransientService, TransientService>(Reuse.Transient);
    r.Register<IScopedService, ScopedService>(Reuse.Scoped);
 }
```

And if I try to do this in one service:

```
var myScopedServvie = Container.Resolve<IScopedService>();
```

I have the exception:
ContainerException: Unable to resolve IScopedService IsResolutionCall
from Container without Scope
with Rules with {CaptureContainerDisposeStackTrace}
with Made={PropertiesAndFields=}

So my question: how can I open a scope for each request of my API?
I can see some tests where there is:

```
(var scope = container.OpenScope())
...
```

But I don't know how to use this code in my application.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A scope will be automatically open per each web request by Asp .Net Core framework, you don't need to bother.

If you want to test the container setup, then you may `OpenScope` manually in the respective test, and resolve from the returned scope.

Comment: Is it possible ot inject built-in types like IHttpClientFactory with a CurrentScopeReuse or WebRequestReuse (probably in the presence of DryIoc.Web) to ctor in Mef mode without a programmatical Resolve<>() call? However one workaround could be to have a wrapper but I'm afraid that I've missed another straight solution. Thank you

Comment: @abbasali-hashemian I am not sure if I follow, may you provide more context and the example in the separate question?